# How can I make the Javascript console NOT print the return value of a function

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function,
it looks similar to this
(I'm making an obfuscation program for those who are interested, that's why I wont share the actual code)

```js
function compile(r,b){
//Do 'stuff' to the inputs
console.log(enc);
return enc
}
```

basically I want to be able to nest functions but not double display the output
(double display would look like this:

```js
> compile("value","value")
< output
< output
```

I dont want this, but I cant remove the console.log because the output isnt the exact same.
if I remove the return statement it does this:

```js
> compile("value","value")
< output
> decompile(compile("value","value"))
< undefined
```

it gives undefined because the compile function doesnt return anything.

The reason I "can't" remove the console.log is as follows:

```js
> console.log("Hi\nHow are you?")
< Hi
< How are you?
```

return:

```js
> function example(){
> return "Hi\nHow are you?"
>}
< 'Hi\nHow are you?'
```

This is why I want to keep the console.log statement
as you can see they do "the same thing"
but display their output differently

How do I make it to the return value of a function is invisible?

Comment: Why do you need to use the console only?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but I believe the answer you're looking for is as follows:
I'm running code inside the developer console (like the one in your browser) because its easier and I don't want to install Node.js (I probably should I just don't want too)

Comment: "*I cant remove the console.log because the output isnt the exact same.*" - not sure what you mean by that. You should absolutely remove the `console.log` statement from the function! If you want to use `console.log` for some reason instead of the implicit printing of the result value in a repl, use `console.log(compile("value","value"))`

Comment: I call baloney on the obfuscation excuse for not sharing your attempt and anyway: "Don't worry about people stealing your ideas. If your ideas are any good, you'll have to ram them down people's throats." -- Howard Aiken

Comment: @Bergi The console.log and the return both have the same input but they display it differently:
console.log("text\ntext") looks different from
return "text\ntext"

Comment: There's a trivial solution where you pass an array or object to the `compile` function, and then store the output in that array or object without returning anything. The entire exercise feels completely pointless though.

Comment: I thought about that, but then I would have to do this:
```javascript
compile("value","value")
decompile(compileoutput)
```
where compileoutput is set globally inside the compile function

Comment: "*I want to keep the `console.log` statement as you can see they do "the same thing" but display their output differently*" - ah I see. But when you want to keep the `console.log`, you should simply **keep it out(side) of the function**, and log the call result: `console.log(compile("value","value"))`

Comment: That could work, let me see how I could implement that

Comment: That Works! (I know I didn't mention this, big brain fart on my part) I added that into my ```javascript
String.prototype.compile
``` function and it works just how I wanted it to. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dexygen, Good point, I'm still not going to reveal the actual code, but I will say its similar to JSF*ck
JSF*ck only uses the characters ()+![]
while my "compiler" only uses the characters ()+!</*[]=
JSF*ck: http://www.jsfuck.com
My code would look like this:
```(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!![] + +!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![] + +!![]]+"y"```
(Without the "y", but the full version is too long for a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to keep the `console.log` statement - as you can see they do "the same thing" but display their output differently"

When you want to keep the `console.log` to have it print the string on multiple lines, you should **keep it out(side) of the function**, and log the call result:

```
console.log(compile("value","value"))
```

If this is too cumbersome to use, write a second function besides `compile`:

```
function compile(r, b) {
  // Do stuff to the inputs
  return enc;
}
function compileAndPrint(r, b) {
  const enc = compile(r, b);
  console.log(enc);
  // return enc;
}
```

then you only need to call

```
compileAndPrint("value","value")
```

If you have multiple functions where you need this, you can also write a generic decorator:

```
function withPrintResult(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
     const result = fn.apply(this, args);
     console.log(result);
     return result;
  }
}
const compileAndPrint = withPrintResult(compile);
```